# Animation of 3d object loaded programmatically, the storyboard not start with begin

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, rotation, storyboard

I am unable to run the `animation`. I searched the web and on the website, I did hours of changes but the storyboard does not start. I will not use `BeginAnimation`. I hope that my problem can also serve to someone else to understand the `Storyboard`.

```
enter code here

    using HelixToolkit.Wpf;
    using System;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
    using System.Windows.Media.Media3D;

    namespace test_storyboard_02    
    {
       public partial class MainWindow : Window
       {
          public Storyboard myStoryboard = new Storyboard();

          Model3DGroup cubelet;
          public MainWindow()
          {
              InitializeComponent();
          }

          private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
          {
             LoadObj();
             view1.ZoomExtents();

             FrameworkContentElement element = new FrameworkContentElement();
             NameScope.SetNameScope(element, new NameScope());


             AxisAngleRotation3D rotation = new AxisAngleRotation3D(new Vector3D(0, 0, 1), 180);
             RotateTransform3D myRotateTransform3D = new RotateTransform3D(rotation, new Point3D(0, 0, 0));

             cubelet.Transform = myRotateTransform3D;

             element.RegisterName("rotation", rotation);

             DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation();
             animation.By = 5;
             animation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);


             Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, rotation);
             Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath("Angle"));
             myStoryboard.Children.Add(animation);

             myStoryboard.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4);
             myStoryboard.Begin(element, HandoffBehavior.Compose);

         }
         private void LoadObj()
         {
            view1.Children.Clear();
            //cubelets = new Model3DGroup[1, 1, 1];
            cubelet = new Model3DGroup();
            ModelImporter importer = new ModelImporter();
            Model3D ModelCube = importer.Load(@"e:\x.obj");
            cubelet.Children.Add(ModelCube);
            view1.Children.Add(new ModelVisual3D { Content = cubelet });
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are problems in these lines of code :

```
FrameworkContentElement element = new FrameworkContentElement();
NameScope.SetNameScope(element, new NameScope());
...
element.RegisterName("rotation", rotation);
```

Changes :

```
NameScope scope = new NameScope();
FrameworkContentElement element = new FrameworkContentElement();
NameScope.SetNameScope(element, scope);
...
element.RegisterName("rotation", scope);
```

See this solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks @AnjumSKhan, I changed the lines that you told me, but there must be something else the storyborad not work. But your suggestion enlightened me many things, I do other tests and let you know. thank you very much.

Comment: hello  @AnjumSKhan. error after modify line:Name of the target object 'rotation' found, but the object is not a valid destination type.

Answer (score 0):

This is the xaml file that I used.

```
<Window x:Class="test_storyboard_02.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:test_storyboard_02"
    xmlns:HelixToolkit="clr-namespace:HelixToolkit.Wpf;assembly=HelixToolkit.Wpf"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Grid>

    <Canvas Name="LayoutRoot" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="319" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="517">
        <HelixToolkit:HelixViewport3D x:Name="view1" Background="Gray" Height="278" Canvas.Left="25" Canvas.Top="22" Width="463">
            <HelixToolkit:DefaultLights/>
            <!--<local:RubikCube x:Name="cube1" /> -->

        </HelixToolkit:HelixViewport3D>

    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED Finally the program WORKS, thanks to  @AnjumSKhan. I hope that the code that I enclose will also serve to someone else. Thanks also to stackoverflow.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="test_storyboard_02.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:test_storyboard_02"
    xmlns:HelixToolkit="clr-namespace:HelixToolkit.Wpf;assembly=HelixToolkit.Wpf"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Window.Resources>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>

    <Canvas Name="LayoutRoot" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="319" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="517">
        <HelixToolkit:HelixViewport3D x:Name="view1" Background="Gray" Height="278" Canvas.Left="25" Canvas.Top="22" Width="463">
            <HelixToolkit:DefaultLights/>
            <!--<local:RubikCube x:Name="cube1" /> -->
        </HelixToolkit:HelixViewport3D>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
    using HelixToolkit.Wpf;
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Media.Media3D;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace test_storyboard_02
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public Storyboard myStoryboard = new Storyboard();
        public Model3DGroup MainModel3Dgroup = new Model3DGroup();

        Model3DGroup modelFloor;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            LoadObj();
            view1.ZoomExtents();
            NameScope scope = new NameScope();
            FrameworkContentElement element = new FrameworkContentElement();
            NameScope.SetNameScope(element, scope);

            // Create a box  that will be the target
            // of the animation.
            // Material material = HelixToolkit.Wpf.MaterialHelper.CreateMaterial(Colors.DarkBlue);
            // MeshBuilder meshBuilder = new MeshBuilder();
            // meshBuilder.AddBox(new Point3D(0, 0, 0), 200, 200, 200);
            // GeometryModel3D modelFloor = new GeometryModel3D(meshBuilder.ToMesh(), material);
            // modelFloor.SetName("floor");
            // MainModel3Dgroup.Children.Add(modelFloor);

            var lights = new DefaultLights();
            view1.Children.Add(lights);

            ModelVisual3D model_visual = new ModelVisual3D();
            model_visual.Content = modelFloor; 
            view1.Children.Add(model_visual);
            view1.ZoomExtents();

            AxisAngleRotation3D rotation = new AxisAngleRotation3D(new Vector3D(0, 0, 1), 0);
            RotateTransform3D myRotateTransform3D = new RotateTransform3D(rotation, new Point3D(0, 0, 0));

            modelFloor.Transform = myRotateTransform3D;

            element.RegisterName("rotation", rotation);

            // Create two DoubleAnimations and set their properties.
            DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation();
            animation.From = 0;
            animation.To = 200;
            animation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);

            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath("Angle"));
            Storyboard.SetTargetName(animation, "rotation");
            myStoryboard.Children.Add(animation);
            myStoryboard.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);

            // Make the Storyboard a resource.
            this.Resources.Add("unique_id1", myStoryboard);
            myStoryboard.Begin(element, HandoffBehavior.Compose);

        }
        private void LoadObj()
        {
            view1.Children.Clear();
            modelFloor = new Model3DGroup();
            ModelImporter importer = new ModelImporter();
            Model3D ModelCube = importer.Load(@"e:\x.obj");
            modelFloor.Children.Add(ModelCube);
            view1.Children.Add(new ModelVisual3D { Content = modelFloor });
        }
    }
}
```